# Create column datetime datatype with length 8 in SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I want to create a table which will have a column with

```
DateTime
```

as data type and length 8.

Answer (score 2):

`DATETIME` in SQL Server is **always** a binary, 8-byte long column - you *cannot* "define" a length for it (since it's **NOT** a string being stored!)

But if you intend to store just the **date** alone - without any time portion - as the "length of 8" seems to imply - then use the `DATE` datatype instead - that stores **date only** (no time portion)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATETIME2` to specify the precision. See below:

```
DECLARE @dt_1 DATETIME2(1) = GETDATE()
DECLARE @dt_2 DATETIME2(2) = GETDATE()
DECLARE @dt_3 DATETIME2(3) = GETDATE()
DECLARE @dt_4 DATETIME2(4) = GETDATE()
DECLARE @dt_5 DATETIME2(5) = GETDATE()
DECLARE @dt_6 DATETIME2(6) = GETDATE()
DECLARE @dt_7 DATETIME2(7) = GETDATE()

SELECT *
FROM    (
            VALUES
                ('precision 1', @dt_1, DATALENGTH(@dt_1)),
                ('precision 2', @dt_2, DATALENGTH(@dt_2)),
                ('precision 3', @dt_3, DATALENGTH(@dt_3)),
                ('precision 4', @dt_4, DATALENGTH(@dt_4)),
                ('precision 5', @dt_5, DATALENGTH(@dt_5)),
                ('precision 6', @dt_6, DATALENGTH(@dt_6)),
                ('precision 7', @dt_7, DATALENGTH(@dt_7))

        )  AS V (precision, date_value, size)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some compatibility issue with external code, you should use Date if you don't use the time part or Datetime2 otherwise with the precision you need.

If you only want to show 8 characters, for whathever reason, you can cast/convert it (ie. '2015-08-11')

Note that it may be better/wiser to cast and format it in the code outside SQL Server.